# Extract data between HTML tags

Tags: java, html, regex

I have my HTML page as shown below:

```
<htm>

<section class="posts">

      <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "url": "http://schema.org",
          "title": "some Title"
        }
      </script>


    <article class="post">
</html>
```

I want to extract the data between `<script type="application/ld+json">` and `</script>`. I have tried with the following code but its not working.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<script type=\"application\\/ld\\+json\">(.*?)</script>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: yes, you're doing something wrong: regexes on html = bad idea. use a DOM parser...

Comment: Add `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. DOM parser, particularly from http://jsoup.org/download would have been a neater solution but this is a really small toy project, so for speed will go with the regex hack. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex to select the JSON from above HTML

```
<script type="application\/ld\+json">(.*)<\/script>
```

In Java code:

```
String str = "<htm><section class=\"posts\"><script type=\"application/ld+json\">{\"url\": \"http://schema.org\",          \"title\": \"some Title\"}</script><article class=\"post\"></html>";
String regex = "<script type=\"application\\/ld\\+json\">(.*)<\\/script>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

prints

> {"url": "http://schema.org",          "title": "some Title"}

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zN5cP8/1) for explanation

Answer (score 2):

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) may be the best solution for you; it allows you to quickly and easily parse HTML.
For your particular problem (assuming that you are getting the HTML from a String), the following would work:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
Elements scriptElements = doc.select("script[type=\"application/ld+json\"]");
String scriptContent = scriptElements.first().html()
```